# Personalizar autenticação do windows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estou criando uma aplicação onde uso *Windows Authentication* para validação dos dados do usuário. Assim que a aplicação abre, já aparece na primeira página algumas informações daquele usuário logado. Em um outro menu eu abro todos os usuários cadastrados.

Como fazer para clicar no usuário e abrir a mesma página que abre quando eu entro na aplicação, só que com os dados daquela usuário que cliquei?

Essa é a `Index` do meu `PerfilController` que é onde obtenho as informações através da autenticação do windows que quero apresentar assim que o usuário logando entra na aplicação:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var chapa = UserDetails.GetChapa(User.Identity.Name);
    var perfil = db.Perfis.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Chapa == chapa);
    if (perfil == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.Id = perfil.Id;
    return View(perfil);
}
```

Essa é a view `Relatorio` que eu tenho onde retorna a lista e cargo das pessoas que eu tenho cadastradas no banco. Eu queria clicar em "Ver Perfil" e abrir no perfil daquela pessoa que eu cliquei.

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Chapa)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cargo)
    </td>

    <td>
       @* @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) *@|
        @Html.ActionLink("Ver Perfil", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
       @* @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })*@
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Você já tem algum código implementado pra termos um ponto de partida?

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var chapa = UserDetails.GetChapa(User.Identity.Name);
            var perfil = db.Perfis.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Chapa == chapa);
            if (perfil == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Id = perfil.Id;
            return View(perfil);
        }

Comment: Essa é a index do meu perfil onde pego as informações que quero apresentar assim que o usuário entra na aplicação

Comment: Você pode colocar esse comentário na sua pergunta? Clique em `editar` logo abaixo da pergunta e adicione o código. Não esqueça que para colocar código na pergunta, coloque 4 espaços no começo da linha para diferenciar.

Comment: Beleza, coloquei lá. Desculpa é a primeira vez que estou perguntando aqui.

Comment: Ok, sem problemas. Vou te orientando.

Answer (score 2):

Faça outra `Action`, por exemplo, `Details`, no seu `Controller`:

```cs
public ActionResult Usuario(String userName)
{
    var chapa = UserDetails.GetChapa(userName);
    var perfil = db.Perfis.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Chapa == chapa);
    if (perfil == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.Id = perfil.Id;
    return View(perfil);
}
```

Não esqueça de criar o respectivo arquivo de `View`, no caso, `Details.cshtml`.

Para testar, chame no endereço:

> http://endereço de teste:porta/Usuarios/Details/?userName=fulano

Na `View` de Relatório, altere o seguinte:

```cs
<td>
   @* @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) *@|
    @Html.ActionLink("Ver Perfil", "Details", "Usuarios", new { userName = item.Nome }) |
   @* @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })*@
</td>
```

Comment: public class RelatorioController : Controller
    {
        private DataContext db = new DataContext();

        //
        // GET: /Relatorio/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var funcionarios = db.Perfis.ToList();
            return View(funcionarios);
        }

    }
} Eu tenho esse controller onde é listado pra mim todos os perfis que eu tenho cadastrado no banco. O que eu preciso é clicar no nome ou no "ver perfil" que aparece na frente de cada nome e abrir pra mim a tela de perfil inicial só que com os dados dessa pessoa que eu cliquei.

Comment: Ok, vou modificar a resposta pra você.

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Chapa)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cargo)
        </td>

        <td>
           @* @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) *@|
            @Html.ActionLink("Ver Perfil", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
           @* @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })*@
        </td>
    </tr>
} a view

Comment: Pode por favor editar novamente a pergunta e inserir este código como sendo o código da *View*? Como comentário não fica legível.

Comment: @Victor Editei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Ok. Criei a action, criei dentro de relatorios uma view chamada Details. Quando eu faço a busca dá Server Error in '/' application. O que eu preciso colocar na view Details.cshtml?

Comment: Não é em `Relatorios`, é em `UsuariosController`. Tinha me enganado na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela paciência e atenção. Ainda está dando a mesma coisa. Eu estou fazendo alguma referência errada. Recapitulando: Eu tenho um PerfilController que um passei um trecho do código acima. Também tenho um RelatorioController que é onde quero ao clicar obter o perfil de qualquer usuário. Eu acrescentei dentro de Relatorio a action Usuario que vc me informou. Criei uma view Details dentro de relatorio. Então na View Relatorio passei a ter duas pastas: Index e Details. Dentro da pasta Index eu alterei @Html.ActionLink("Ver Perfil"), "Details", "Usuarios", new ( userName = item.Nome }) Erro?

Comment: Descobri o erro. Eu estava trocando o nome das views. Agora quando eu compilo dá um erro " nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code " apontando para a linha 'string chapa = userName.Substring(userName.Indexof(@"\") + 1 ' dentro da minha classe UserDetails

Comment: Aí já é outro erro, possivelmente envolvendo `userName`, que está nulo.

Comment: Mas não está nulo... :/

Comment: Então é colocar o breakpoint na View e ver o que está nulo.